# Why is Flutter adding borders to my containers?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

For some reason on my darker theme, I am getting these odd borders around my containers. I have a `Column` made up of `ProfileMenuItem`'s. There is nothing about any borders in this code. I have a divider I've made to split sections of the menu, but that's showing up correctly. Below is a bit of code and the screenshot. Then my user_profile screen calls this `ProfileMenu` class to render it.

This only seems to be happening on my dark theme and I'm not quite sure why. I don't have any specific theme settings for containers.

And for some odd reason these borders disappear if I scroll to the bottom of the profile menu. Makes no sense.

```
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/saved_tips_icon.svg',
                title: 'Saved tips',
                onTap: () {
                  // something
                }),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/skin_concerns_icon.svg',
                title: 'Skin concerns',
                onTap: () {
                  // something
                }),
            profileDivider(),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/about_icon.svg',
                title: 'About skica',
                onTap: () {
                  _launchWebsiteAbout();
                }),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/feedback_icon.svg',
                title: 'Feedback',
                onTap: () {
                  _launchWebsiteContact();
                }),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/rate_us_icon.svg',
                title: 'Rate us',
                onTap: () {
                  // something
                }),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/facebook_follow_icon.svg',
                title: 'Follow us on Facebook',
                onTap: () {
                  _launchFacebook();
                }),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/rate_us_icon.svg',
                title: 'Invite a friend',
                onTap: () {
                  // something
                }),
            profileDivider(),
            profileMenuItem(
                context: context,
                svgAsset: 'assets/svg/user_profile/logout_icon.svg',
                title: 'Logout',
                onTap: () {
                  _confirmLogout();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget profileDivider({double verticalPadding = 10}) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: verticalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding),
      child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/user_profile/divider.svg'),
    );
  }

  Widget profileMenuItem(
      {@required BuildContext context,
      @required String svgAsset,
      @required String title,
      @required Function onTap}) {
    return Material(
      child: InkWell(
        // When the user taps the button, show a snackbar.
        onTap: onTap,
        splashColor: Colors.orange,
        child: Ink(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: SvgPicture.asset(svgAsset, height: 60),
              
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                child:
                    Text(title, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child:
                      SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/next_icon.svg', height: 34),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]
And here it is if I scroll to the bottom. They magically disappear.
[image]

Comment: Just. found out, its only showing these borders when I'm scrolled to the top of the page. If I scroll down it disappears. I figured maybe its an emulator bug. But, it's also doing this on my release builds on my actual phone.

Comment: Maybe this card have dark background color and it's showing between the items? What color do you see if you hide the ListView?

Comment: @YoBo it's white. I get what you're saying, but if that was the case, the borders wouldnt disappear and look completely normal when you scroll to the bottom. I didn't have that in the OP but it was something I discovered last night. The borders disappear when you scroll down. So odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I discovered through GitHub there is actually an antialiasing issue where the pixels dont translate correctly for some reason. This was cause the color of the Material widget which was gray/black to peek through the 1px gaps in the ProfileMenuItems.

The dark theme was automatically coloring the Material widget gray. So I just set it's color property to white.

Here's the related bug to the antialiasing error: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288